# Ruby Date.strptime doesn't enforce 4-digit year

Tags: ruby, date, strptime

I would expect this code to give me an `ArgumentError: invalid date` error. In Ruby 2.0.0 irb:

```
irb(main):003:0> Date.strptime('05-10-2014', '%Y-%m-%d')
=> #<Date: 0005-10-20 ((1723177j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Am I doing something wrong or will Ruby accept a 2-digit year even when I specify `%Y`?

I am looking at testing user input. In this case my program is expecting it in the `%Y-%m-%d` and the input date was "entered" in the wrong format, but `strptime` says it's ok.

Comment: The [document](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) says four digits at least. What you report goes against it.

Comment: It is misleading to use a string like `'05-10-2014'`. Use `'05-10-20'`.

Comment: How is it misleading to use a 4-digit year?

Comment: I think the OP is asking why strptime is accepting '05-10-2014' as a valid format when a format of '%Y-%m-%d' is required. It should be raising an error that the data given does not match the format.

Comment: @JGraham No, you are not using a 4-digit year. You are using a 2-digit day of month `20` followed by a sequence `14` that does not contribute to parsing. Why is it not misleading to leave a dummy `14`? What is the purpose of leaving it?

Comment: @infused has it correct. The date string I'm passing in is incorrect on purpose, yet strptime says it's valid.

Comment: You just try `-d` and `-m`.. This is more **stricter** than `m` and `d`.

Comment: @sawa yes the string is incorrect. But why does strptime say it's valid? And please - there's no need to insult my "comprehension skill" here.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I tried the `-d` and `-m` and it always gave me `invalid date` even when I entered a correct one. Are those just for use with `strftime`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a Ruby bug opened for this issue last year, but it was rejected. I guess the Ruby team feels that this is valid behavior.

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8941